# Anonymous Error in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am populating `List<Object>` data which is retrieving from Local DB.It is well populated in Initial Time. I am having 13 tabs here.Depends on Category I am populating Products.

I'm moving towards Right like Backery `-->` Bowl`-->`Box`-->` Cups  ===> Everything is  fine.
 **(Like Image 1)**

But when I swipe towards  Backery `<--` Bowl `<--`Box `<--`Cups  ==> Set all the data.
 **(Like Image 2)**

But in LogCat it prints the correct data.

[image: Image 1]

================================

[image: Image 2]

Coding is Here:

TabFragmentSearch newInstance value is return from MainActivity.

```
public static TabFragmentSearch newInstance(int categoryId, String categoryName) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
    args.putString(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_NAME, categoryName);

    Log.e("TabFragmnet Instance", categoryId + " " + categoryName);

    TabFragmentSearch fragment = new TabFragmentSearch();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

 =======================

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        config = new Config(getActivity());
        context = getActivity();
        CommonUtil.pref = context.getSharedPreferences(CommonUtil.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        commonUtil.dbUtil = new DbUtil(context);
        commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
        commonUtil.dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_rv);
        edtSearch = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
        noData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noData);
        noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RestaurantDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

        swipeCheck = false;

        cartRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
        RestaurantDataSet = MainActivity.cartRestaurant;

        int BeanCatId = getArguments().getInt(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_ID);

        Config.startFilterClicked = false;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
        editor1.putBoolean("startFilter", Config.startFilterClicked);
        editor1.commit();

        Cursor curCAT_PDT = commonUtil.dbUtil.getCAT_PDT(String.valueOf(BeanCatId));

        if (curCAT_PDT != null && curCAT_PDT.getCount() > 0) {
            curCAT_PDT.moveToFirst();
            int i = 0;
            do {
                cartRestaurant.add(new CartRes(curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_NAME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_PRODUCT_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_PRODUCT_NAME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_SALES_PRICE)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_IMAGE_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_SHOP_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_DELIVERY_TIME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_LIKECOUNT)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_VOUCHER_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_VOUCHER_OFFER))));

                System.out.println("Restaurant  category id = " + cartRestaurant.get(0).JSON_CATEGORY_ID + " name = " + cartRestaurant.get(i).JSON_CATEGORY_NAME);
                i++;
            } while (curCAT_PDT.moveToNext());

            CardAdapter adapter1 = new CardAdapter(cartRestaurant, context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        edtSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + " query" + query);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, query);
                if (filteredModelList.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Search Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + "newText " + newText);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, newText);

                adapter = new CardAdapter(filteredModelList, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        edtSearch.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                edtSearch.clearFocus();

                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                return false;
            }
        });
        noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing,**From**

## final List filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, query);

## **to**

## final List filteredModelList = filter(cartRestaurant, query);

```
 edtSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + " query" + query);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, query);
                if (filteredModelList.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Search Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + "newText " + newText);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, newText);

                adapter = new CardAdapter(filteredModelList, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                return true;
            }
        });
```